# Left Join resulting in zero output

Tags: mysql, sql

Am I using the correct Join here? Trying to figure out what is wrong in my code. Tried changing the join between Inner, Outer, and Right just to throw something against the wall.

```
SELECT users.region, count(internal_profile_views.user_id)
from users
Left JOIN internal_profile_views
ON users.id = internal_profile_views.user_id
AND users.id = internal_profile_views.viewed_user_id
GROUP BY users.region;
```

Table Schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFUZO.jpg

Output I am getting:

West 0
Northeast 0
South 0
Other 0
Midwest 0

Comment: How are we supposed to know wether you're using the correct join? It depends on what you're trying to do. This is like asking if you're using the right tool without telling us if you're trying to hit a nail, screw a screw or cut a piece of wood.

Comment: So what do you want to see from this schema? Please explain in simple english and include an example output recordset (just build this by hand) Then we can explain how to correctly join between the tables to achieve the desired outcome

Comment: I know you are going to get zero results with your query, I am interested in knowing what you are expecting, some sort of statement like _"Display the number of Views by Region that the viewer is in"_

Comment: What does `viewed_user_id` represent, the owner of the profile, or the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

From your schema, is looks like `internal_profile_views` represents a M:N table between the *User Profile* and the *Users who view the profile*.

In that case a row in `internal_profile_views` that has the same value for `user_id` and `viewed_user_id` represents a user who is looking at their own profile, a row that has different values for these fields represents a user looking at someone elses profile.

In your join statement, you have used a criteria where both `user_id` and `viewed_user_id` **MUST** match the same `users.id` record to be included in the results. Most likely you only intended to join on *one* of these columns, not both.

> From your schema the relationship between `viewed_user_id` and `user_id` in the `internal_profile_views` is ambiguous if my assumption is incorrect, just replace the usage of those columns in the following queries

Having established that, you query is likely one of these:

```
SELECT viewer.region as Viewer_Region, count(views.user_id) as Unique_Viewers
FROM internal_profile_views views
INNER JOIN users viewer ON views.user_id = viewer.id
GROUP BY viewer.region;
```

```
SELECT profileOwner.region as Profile_Region, count(views.user_id) as Unique_Viewers
FROM internal_profile_views views
INNER JOIN users profileOwner ON views.viewed_user_id = profileOwner.Id
INNER JOIN users viewer ON views.user_id = viewer.id
GROUP BY users.region;
```